# App Engine managed VM and Jersey SSE

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey, jetty, server-sent-events

I've tried to setup an App Engine managed VM to run [Jersey SSE (Server-Sent events) using broadcasting](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html#d0e11592), but it seems something is locking when hitting the resource on the VM. Most of the VM runtime code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-vm-runtime).

When I run the code in my own Jetty distribution (v9.2.5, fresh, no configuration), everything works fine. POSTing result in the message being broadcasted to the listeners that called the GET method.

When running on the App Engine VM runtime, the EventOuput is beeing added to the SseBroadcaster, but the messages never reach the clients. Here is the REST resource I'm using.

```
@Singleton
@Path("broadcast")
public static class BroadcasterResource {
    private SseBroadcaster broadcaster = new SseBroadcaster();

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String broadcastMessage(String message) {
        OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
        OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.name("message")
            .mediaType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
            .data(String.class, message)
            .build();

        broadcaster.broadcast(event);

        return "Message '" + message + "' has been broadcast.";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public EventOutput listenToBroadcast() {
        final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
        this.broadcaster.add(eventOutput);
        return eventOutput;
    }
}
```

I did have to add the following to my web.xml to enable the App Engine registered filters `async-supported` configuration

```
<!-- ==================================================================== -->
<!-- By default, the AbandonedTransactionDetector filter is mapped to all -->
<!-- servlets.  This filter rolls back any transactions that are still    -->
<!-- active when the request completes.                                   -->
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>AbandonedTransactionDetector</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter
    </filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AbandonedTransactionDetector</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- ==================================================================== -->
<!-- By default, the SaveSessionFilter filter is mapped to all servlets.  -->
<!-- This filter saves any dirty sessions to the datastore and memcache.  -->
<!-- ==================================================================== -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>SaveSessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SaveSessionFilter
    </filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SaveSessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>_ah_ParseBlobUploadFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter
    </filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>_ah_ParseBlobUploadFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Thoughts on what might be missing?

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but I discovered that websockets are disabled with the appengine-java-runtime. It comes down to a check in Jetty for the context holder class and App Engine uses a custom one so it fails.. Anyway, I switched to Atmosphere for now